# Heroku toolbelt error

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to deploy node.js app on heroku for the first time. As instructed I installed heroku toolbelt but something is wrong.
My machine with windows 10 using heroku toolbelt
Issue:

> C:\Users(username)\Downloads\Heroku [master]> heroku login heroku-cli:
> Installing Toolbelt v4... ! Heroku client internal error. ! Search for
> help at: https://help.heroku.com ! Or report a bug at:
> https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new
>
> Error:       getaddrinfo: No such host is known.
> (SocketError(Excon::Errors::SocketError) Command:     heroku login
> Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.42.45 (i386-mingw32) ruby/2.1.7 Error
> ID:    c47aaf8f037042beb25fdceb46cfe78f
>
> More information in C:/Users/courtaks/.heroku/error.log

## --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## Solved:

as instructed by the heroku team in this isssue: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1939 
it appears to be a temporary DNS issue. 
it's working now. 
I didn't do anything except waiting the problem to solve it self. also try changing your dns server, maybe that will work.

## --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: And log file content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost 6 months later, I got the exact same issue on the first interaction with heroku, not a good start.

I used the command to verify the installation:

```
heroku --version
```

It probably needs some additional data downloading for the first start and installing/preparing heroku-cli.

I am behind a corporate firewall and git + npm are working perfectly fine (after one-time proxy configuration).

The issue resolved automatically after some time along with initial frustration and time consumption. Just shared my experience for any next user landing here until the issue is actually resolved.

Log File extract:

> Heroku client internal error. getaddrinfo: No such host is known. 
>   (SocketError)
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   Heroku client internal error. getaddrinfo: This is
>   usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that
>   the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative
>   server.  (SocketError)

[*cross posted partially on the given heroku git link, same like the original question and answer*]

Answer (score 0):

## --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

## Solved:

as instructed by the heroku team in this isssue: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/1939 
it appears to be a temporary DNS issue. 
it's working now. 
I didn't do anything except waiting the problem to solve it self. also try changing your dns server, maybe that will work.

## --------------------------------------------------------------------------------